# php array_combine function is not working properly?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code

```
        $pro_qty = '';
        $se_pro = '';

        $pro_id_nn = $this->getDataAll("SELECT session_pro_id,session_pro_qty FROM `jp_session` WHERE session_pro_id IN (".$pro_id.") AND order_status='3'");

        foreach($pro_id_nn as $pro)
        {
            $pro_qty[] = $pro['session_pro_qty'];
            $se_pro[] = $pro['session_pro_id'];

        }
        $proqty = array_combine($pro_qty,$se_pro);
        echo '<br>';
        print_r($se_pro);
        echo '<br>';
        print_r($pro_qty);
        echo '<br>';
        print_r($proqty);
```

**OUTOUT**

first array

```
$se_pro = Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 ) ;
```

second array

```
$pro_qty = Array ( [0] => 24 [1] => 24 [2] => 22 ) ;
```

Finally combine two array result is

```
$proqty = Array ( [5] => 24 [1] => 22 );
```

but my expecting result is

```
$proqty = Array ( [5] => 24 [1] => 24 [1] => 22 );
```

how can i get my expecting result . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple solution

```
foreach($pro_id_nn as $pro)
    {
        $pro_qty[$pro['session_pro_id']][] = $pro['session_pro_qty'];
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your expected result is not possible, you cannot map one key (1) to two different values (24 and 22).  Perhaps you should look at a different solution, such as a "jp_session" class which contains the two values, and then just store it in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php
$se_pro = Array ( 0 => 5, 1 => 1, 2 => 1 ) ;
$pro_qty = Array ( 0 => 24, 1 => 24, 2 => 22 ) ;
$a=sizeof($se_pro);
for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++)
{
  $b=$se_pro[$i];
  $c=$pro_qty[$i];
  $temp[$b]=$c;
  $i++;
}
print_r($temp);
?>
```

But one condition  '$se_pro' values not repeat and both array are same size

Comment: yes, working but  $se_pro value 1 repeating and third time loop run [1] =>'' over writes with another value.  But one condition '$se_pro' values not repeat and both array are same size. The above condition satisfy then you will get you expected output

Answer (score 0):

in `array_combine()` If two keys are the same, the second one prevails..

you can get the result like -

```
Array
(
    [24] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 1
        )

    [22] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

the other way can be

```
$keys   = array ( '24', '24', '22' );
$values = array ( '5', '1', '1' );
$output = array();

$size = sizeof($keys);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++ ) {
    if ( !isset($output[$keys[$i]]) ) {
        $output[$keys[$i]] = array();
    }
    $output[$keys[$i]][] = $values[$i];
}
```

this will give the output like -

```
Array ( [24] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 1 ) [22] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) )
```

or you can use

```
<?php

    $keys   = array ( '24', '24', '22' );
    $values = array ( '5', '1', '1' );
function foo($key, $val) {
   return array($key=>$val);
}

$arrResult = array_map('foo', $keys, $values);

print_r($arrResult);

?>
```

depending upon which output is more suitable for you to work with.